# BeanCreationException for RequestMappingHandlerMapping when jackson-jaxrs removed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

My spring application fails to start with error -

Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed ; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException

I have removed dependency for jackson-jaxrs of version 1.9.13
and instead have added dependencies for com.fasterxml.jackson.core - jackson-databind , jackson-annotations , jackson-core version 2.10

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is used in the code.

The code compiles succcessfully though.

Version used are -
Spring framework - 4.3 ,
Spring security - 4.2 ,
Spring oauth2 - 2.4.1
It isn't spring boot application

Why does it still refer to org.code.jackson ?

Comment: Is it a maven project ?

Comment: Are you using JsonParseException  anywhere in the code ? If yes, then remove it.

Comment: it's a maven project . Due to vulnerability issues I have to replace org.codehaus.jackson with proper dependencies from com.fasterxml.jackson. I have added the correct version 2.10 as I already mentioned. Is there a way to figure out why org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException is thrown when I am not using org/codehaus/jackson/ anywhere?

Comment: Please read my answer. I have explained the things you can do :)

Comment: jackson-core-asl is not supposed to be used. Instead the jackson-core is used as mentioned in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl

Comment: I gave a workaround if the bug was not resolved. Is it solved ?

Comment: Do mvn clean install to refresh the project. After refresh, run the code and check whether the same error is coming or not.

Comment: Are you able to resolve now ?

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I need to check what's happening. It's not very clear.